# Smooch.io .createConversation() is not a method

Tags: javascript, chatbot, smooch

I have a chatbot based on Smooch.io and I am trying to show a menu on chat initialization so user can start from here instead of typing anything.

As far as I understand from the docs, to do that I need to create conversation `Smooch.startConversation();` and then send stuff from my backend app. However it gives me "Smooch.startConversation();" error.

So my question is 1) What I am doing wrong here?; 2) Is there any other way to show initial menu instead of starting conversation without user yet messaging anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming you're using the latest version of the SDK**, you're probably calling `startConversation` before the SDK has finished initializing.

You should wait for the promise returned by `init` to resolve before calling `startConversation`. Like this:

```
Smooch.init({appId: '<app-id>'})
  .then(() => {
    Smooch.startConversation();
  })
```

Comment: actually I am calling `Smooch.startConversation();` in onReady block (and i assume it means Smooch is initialized already)

Comment: onReady doesn't mean that Smooch is initialized. The `Smoochinit` call is asynchronous and returns a Promise which it resolves when complete.